# MappingException: "No property found on entity to bind constructor parameter to"?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, hibernate, spring-data-mongodb

I developed my project with spring data mongodb, and used to have this document:

```
@Document(collection="Instrument")
public class Instrument {
@Id
private Integer id;

private String name;

private String internalCode;

private String fosMarketId;

private String localCode;

//setters...getters... and constructurs....
```

Now I need to add some property to my document as bellow:

```
....

private Long from;

private Long to;

private Long OpenHourfrom;

private Long OpenHourTo;

private Boolean isActive;

//setters...getters... and constructurs....
```

so I have this new constructor:

```
    @PersistenceConstructor
public Instrument(Integer id, String name, String internalCode, String fosMarketId, String localCode, Long from,
        Long to, Long openHourfrom, Long openHourTo, Boolean isActive) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.internalCode = internalCode;
    this.fosMarketId = fosMarketId;
    this.localCode = localCode;
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.OpenHourfrom = openHourfrom;
    this.OpenHourTo = openHourTo;
    this.isActive = isActive;
}
```

but when I run one of repo methods this exception had thrown:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No property openHourfrom found on entity class com.tosan.entity.Instrument to bind constructor parameter to!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:74)
at ....
```

Note that I use spring-confix.xml with bellow settings:

```
    <mongo:mongo-client 
    host="IP" port="Port"  >
<mongo:client-options write-concern="NORMAL" 
            connections-per-host="1000"
                threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="600"
                connect-timeout="10000"
                max-wait-time="15000"                   
                socket-keep-alive="true"
                socket-timeout="15000"
    />
</mongo:mongo-client>
```

I wonder how can I set auto update property of hibernate spring to true, so that I could update my document and add new properties.

Comment: the variable name is `OpenHourfrom` in field definition. change that to `openHourfrom`

or rename the parameter in the constructor!

Comment: @enator Your' right! simply That was the problem! I wonder how stupid I was!

Answer (score 1):

Although not applicable to the subject of this topic, in some cases, adding no args constructor to the document entity will solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

my problem was, that I set a property inside the entity by

```
ticker.setLastPrice(new LastPriceDbo() {{ setPrice(...) }}
```

when I changed to

```
var lastPrice = new LastPriceDbo();
lastPrice.setPrice(...)
ticker.setLastPrice(lastPrice);
```

it worked

Answer (score 1):

For some people in the future (Dec 2022).

As someone mentioned before:
,,The MongoRepository defined custom query methods use the constructor parameter names for locate the property to use in search, so this parameters names must be have the same same as the Document entity properties."

Example:

```
@Data                           //Lombok creates constructor and Getter/Setter methods
@Document()                     //User is Collection class
public class User {
 @Id
 private String id;
 private Gender Gender;
 
 public User(Gender Gender) {
        this.Gender = Gender;
}}
```

Normally IntelliJ creates the constructur with lowercase parameter like

```
User(Gender gender){
  Gender = gender;
}
```

Change it to this, because in this case the entity name "Gender" in User class is in uppercase, so the Parameter should also be in uppercase, for some reason.

```
User(Gender Gender){
  this.Gender = Gender;
}

public enum Gender {
    MALE, FEMALE
}
```

This problem doesn't show up when I was creating the user, only if my
service was using MongoRepository:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}




public interface UserRepository  extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
    //Optional<User> findUserByEmail(String email);
}
```

This was my case, maybe you have some other problems.
Keep going buddys.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;`
   `@Field` annotaion for each filed
2. Check constuctor of entity class and make sure parameter names are correct

Comment: As @enator stated in his comment, my problem solved by simply camel cased field.

Answer (score 0):

The MongoRepository defined custom query methods use the constructor parameter names for locate the property to use in search, so this parameters names must be have the same same as the Document entity properties.